# How to check specific value and replace in specific column of a csv file in php

Tags: php

How to check specific value and replace in specific column of a csv file in php

1. USA in col B
2. check USA in col B
3. Replace with new value India in Col B

Have tried with below code but not successful.

```
$lines = file("csvfile.csv", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
    $lines = array_map("str_getcsv", $lines);
    
    $input = ["row" => 1, "column" => 1];
    $lines[$input["row"]][$input["column"]] = "USA";
    
    $fp = fopen('csvfile.csv', 'w');
    
    foreach ($lines as $line) {
    if ($line[1] == 'USA') {
        echo "exist";
        $line[1] = 'India';
    }
    fputcsv($fp, $line);
}
    fclose($fp);
```

I am new in php,please help

With the help of
Barmar Sir, I got the result.but data should have available in col A.

Answer (score 2):

Do the replacement in the `foreach` loop, before writing to the output file.

Loop through all the fields in the line, replacing it if it matches.

```
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($line); $i++) {
        if ($line[$i] == 'USA') {
            $line[$i] = 'India';
        }
    }
    fputcsv($fp, $line);
}
```

Comment: After suggestion, have edited code like below but showing  Undefined array key 1 for this line if ($line[1] == 'USA'), please edit my code for require output.

Comment: That means some lines of the file don't have 2 fields. You should figure out why. You can skip those lines with another `if` statement.

Comment: Actually, in csv file, B column has 10 times USA Like B1, B2, .... B10 and want to replace all USA with India, I want to request to you, please edit my code for require output, I am totally new in php,, don't know where i can correct. If it is possible. I am worried about the week

Comment: That's not one column, that's 10 different columns, since `,` is the separator between columns.

Comment: I understand your suggestion, and i add some data in Col A, and Got result. Thanks Too much, Thanks Too much Thanks Too muchThanks Too muchThanks Too muchThanks Too muchThanks Too muchThanks Too muchThanks Too muchThanks Too muchThanks Too muchThanks Too muchThanks Too muchThanks Too muchThanks Too muchThanks Too muchThanks Too muchThanks Too muchThanks Too muchThanks Too muchThanks Too muchThanks Too much